# Array to string conversion

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

There is an error in my code but the code works perfectly. I mean all the values are inserted in the database but there is an error like this on the screen:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: models/some_model.php
>
> Line Number: 106

This is my code:

**View:**

```
<?php foreach($app as $row){
    echo "<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=appname[]  value='".$row->app_name."'/>".$row->id."</td><td>".$row->app_name."</td><tr>".
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function hide(){
    $this->load->model('some_model');
    $visi = $this->input->post('appname');
    $success = $this->some_model->hideApp($visi);

    foreach($visi as $key=>$value)
    {
    $success = $this->some_model->hideApp($visi[$key]);
    }

    if($success == TRUE)
        $this->hideApp_page(TRUE);
    else $this->hideApp_page(FALSE);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function hideApp($visi){
    $visi = $this->db->escape_str($visi);
    $queryStr = "UPDATE appwarehouse.application_table SET visibility='hidden' where app_name='$visi';"; /* this is line 106*/
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: In the line 106 you are using an array as if it was string.

Comment: Would you identify which one line 106 is?

Comment: line 106 is 
    $queryStr = "UPDATE appwarehouse.application_table SET visibility='hidden' where app_name='$visi';";

Comment: Great. Put `print_r($visi); exit();` before it, and see what it contains. Maybe `appname` uses the `<input>` array format i.e. with square brackets in the HTML, and PHP has converted it to an array for you?

Comment: i saw the values of array but how do i remove the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$visi is array like [1,2,3,4]
when you put $visi in hideApp()
it will be display "array to string error"
so maybe you can remove this line `$success = $this->some_model->hideApp($visi);`
you have already do `some_model->hideApp($visi[$key])` in the foreach loop
so i don't know why you write this`$success = $this->some_model->hideApp($visi);`

if you still want to run `$success = $this->some_model->hideApp($visi);`
you have to put $visi into a string